# numpy get the index of a specific value, occuring after a given index

Tags: python, numpy

I got the following numpy array

```
print(data)

Out: array([[[94 32 63]
  [56 19 48]
  [29 11 45]
  [15 29 33]]

 [[60 16 57]
  [26 36 62]
  [29 56 88]
  [96 66 75]]

 [[83 52 66]
  [28  9 95]
  [88 86 69]
  [26 78 56]]

 [[84 29 98]
  [83  0 38]
  [87 11 71]
  [27 51 37]]

 [[11 25  5]
  [19 10 13]
  [ 8 21  3]
  [ 7  5  1]]])
```

I would like to find where (at which index) I have the closest value to 50% of max along axis 0, the value here in `decay_value`

```
max_value = np.max(data, axis=0)
threshold_decay = 0.5
decay_value = max_value*threshold_decay
```

But I would like to search it in the slice of the array **after** (at higher position) the position of the maximum

So basically after the value expressed by the `index` as below

```
index = np.argmax(data, axis=0)
print (index)

Out:array([[0 2 3]
           [3 1 2]
           [2 2 1]
           [1 2 1]])
```

The code below allows me to get the position of the closest value to `threshold_decay`
but of course that could occur at whatever index position, even before (at lower position) the index of the maximum value.

```
difference_dummy = np.absolute(data - decay_value)
index_decay = np.argmin(data, axis=0)
print(index_decay)

Out: array([[4, 1, 4],
            [4, 3, 4],
            [4, 0, 4],
            [4, 4, 4]])
```

Indeed the results I'm looking at would be the following

```
Out: array([[4, 4, 4],
            [4, 3, 4],
            [4, 4, 4],
            [4, 4, 4]])
```

As the matrix I'm  working with could be quite large I would appreciate any *pythonic* solution without loops

Comment: Let me add the context. I'm working with time series, so the index position resamble the time, that is why I need to consider the elements after a given index, it is like search an event occuring after a given date.